# Inconsistencies of the positions in a linear VEINS car flow

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to monitor positions (X coordinate, it is horizontal) of vehicles in a linear flow.

In **TraCIDemo11p::handlePositionUpdate** method, I added current vehicle position (by getCurrentPosition().x) and vehicle id (by getExternalId()) to message data using,

***wsm ->setWsmData (parameters)***  and sent it down via ***sendDown(wsm)***.

Then in **TraCIDemo11p::onWSM(WaveShortMessage* wsm)**, those information is retrieved and added to a std::map which I use for my calculations.

However in an arbitary momnet during the simulation vehicle positions can be found like this (v0:439.60 v1:389.60 v2:339.60 v3:339.60 v4:289.60) in the map. This is because v2 has not updated its position after v3 updated its position. I would appreciate any advice on this to avoid this inconsistency.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered that the update message of v2 might have gotten lost on the way from sender to receiver?

Comment: Thank you very much for asking and sorry for the late reply. While looking for an answer, I realized that BSM's contains the primary information such as position and speed so I do not need to create a WSM and manipulate its data property. So I overrode OnBSM inside TraCIDemo11p.cc, and the problem the list got updated more frequently than previously in such way that solves my problem. I commented OnWSM entirely out. I still do not have 100% clearance on why it did not happen with WSM.

Comment: Further I found that 'BaseWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(msg)' inside handleSelfMsg plays a role here. How does handleSelfMsg  get called though I do not schedule self messages in TraCIDemo11p? I would highly appreciate if you can provide me an insight. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered that a superclass might have scheduled a self message?

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I am digging into the code now and yes, BaseWaveAppLayer class has implemented it.

Comment: Can this be a result of lane change or any traffic condition like breaking due to road network congestion? Is it recurring?